# Ouside borders dynamic ranges

Tags: excel, dynamic, border, vba

I have searched for my answer and have had no luck. What I am looking to do is move the bottom border I currently have 8 sets of data on one page. Ranges are `B4:E7`, `G4:I7`, `B11:E14`, `G11:I14`, `B18:E40`, `G18:I40`, `G44:E66`, and `G44:I66`. I have the border set in the template and I have VBA to hide cells if there is no value present.

I am looking to macro in the bottom border as the ranges have data. I have tried naming the ranges and using borderaround but that keeps to the original named range. I have found no code that is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the module below which does exactly what you had asked for.  I just noticed your answer, but from your question it seemed like you were looking for something more dynamic, not just the code to add a border.  Just as an FYI, in the future you can use the macro record to get code like that.

```
Sub DynamicBorders()

Dim arrRange1() As String
Dim arrRange2() As String
Dim i As Integer, x As Integer
Dim strLeft As String
Dim strRight As String

arrRange1 = Split("B4,G4,B11,G11,B18,G18,B44,G44", ",")
arrRange2 = Split("E7,I7,E14,I14,E40,I40,E66,I66", ",")

For i = LBound(arrRange1) To UBound(arrRange1)
    'Determine if the range is 2 or 3 charaters long, then set x = row number
    If Len(arrRange2(i)) = 2 Then
      x = Right(arrRange2(i), 1)
    ElseIf Len(arrRange2(i)) = 3 Then
      x = Right(arrRange2(i), 2)
    End If

    If ActiveSheet.Rows(x).Hidden = True Then
      'Find the first row that is not hidden
      Do Until ActiveSheet.Rows(x).Hidden = False
        x = x - 1
      Loop

      'Get the column letter of the range
      strLeft = Left(arrRange1(i), 1)
      strRight = Left(arrRange2(i), 1)

      'Select the range of cells across the bottom and set the border to black
      ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(x, strLeft), ActiveSheet.Cells(x, strRight)).Select
      With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = vbBlack
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
      End With

    Else
      'If the last row is not hidden, then clear any previous border that was added
      'Note - you may want to add this as a seperate module to 'reset' the borders
      strLeft = arrRange1(i)
      strRight = arrRange2(i)
      ActiveSheet.Range(strLeft & ":" & strRight).Select
      Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    End If

  Next i

  ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
  End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. It is apparent that I need to learn more about this.

Comment: I am sorry, I was new to the form and didn't read how to give you credit. Thank you @phillip. I implemented your code and it works like a charm.

Comment: No problem, we all start at the same place.  If the answer solves your problem though you are encouraged to click on the check-mark to accept it .

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an answer and have tested it.

```
With Range("s_" & i)  
    With .Rows(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count)   
        With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)  
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous  
            .Weight = xlMedium  
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic  
        End With  
    End With  
End With
```